# MCMC sampling from a convex set

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, rejection-sampling

Suppose that we are given the matrix,

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}6/5 & 3 & -3/10 & -4/10\\
7/5 & -7/10 & 7/10 & 14/5\\
-6/10 & -7/10  &-1/2 & 3/10\\
12/5 & 1 & 2 & 3/2\\
 -3/5 & 4/5 & -1/2 & 12/5\\
4/5 & 2 & -1 & -3/10\\
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 &  0 & 1 & -1\\
1 & -1 &  0 &  0 \end{pmatrix} $$

I've been given a problem asking to sample points using a Metropolis Hastings algorithm in $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^4$ from the polytope,

$$ R = \{\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^4 : Ax \geq b\} $$

where $b = \begin{pmatrix}-1,&-1,&-1,&-1,&-1,&-1,&-1,&-1,&-1\end{pmatrix}^T \in \mathbb{R}^9$. I really have no clue how to begin here:

How are we supposed to find a suitable transition function $q(\textbf{y} | \textbf{x})$ for such a complicated set? Typically we require some function that is proportional to the density of $\textbf{x}$. How can we find such a function as well?

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Metropolis Hastings is used to sample from a probability distribution. You specify that $x$ must lie in a given polytope, but what's the distribution?

Comment: If you mean to simulate the Uniform distribution on that set $R$, a random walk will do, rejecting proposals that fall outside the set.

Comment: @Xi'an in your answer, the probability of moving from the boundaries can be hard to determine?

Comment: @ZHU: the MH acceptance probability remains the same whether or not the chain is at the boundary. If you mean that the chain can get stuck in a corner, it all depends on the topology of the boundaries and on the scale of the random walk.